# How can I add single quotes as separators?

Tags: sql, sql-server, variables, types

I have this data result as a nvarchar that i need to compare using IN conditions.

How can I turn this nvarchar '1,2,3,4,5' into '1', '2', '3', '4', '5'?

Comment: What is your database? Sql Server? MySQl?...

Comment: [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: This is SQL SERVER

Answer (score 1):

Use this — here is the [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/4be6c/4):

```
REPLACE('1,2,3,4,5',  ',', ''',''')
```

If above one does not work then use this:

```
'''' + REPLACE('1,2,3,4,5',  ',', ''',''') + ''''
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `in` -- directly.  Instead, split the string:

```
where col in (select s.value from string_split('1,2,3,4,5', ',') s)
```

Comment: Can't use string_split() funuction coz im having a compatibility of 100 only.